# Regex - making the match non greedy

Tags: java, regex

I have a String as given below. It is **NOT JSON**

`"city":"atlanta","this1":"that1","state":"GA","city":"dallas","this2":"that2","state":"TX"`

My requirement is get the name of the city for the given state using regex.  between city and state parameters I might have varying number of parameters.

This regex pattern seems to be greedy - matches city from atlanta for the above String

```
"city":"(.*?)".*?"state":"TX"
```

matches

```
"city":"atlanta","this1":"that1","state":"GA","city":"dallas","this2":"that2","state":"TX"
```

I am looking for a match like this.

```
"city":"dallas","this2":"that2","state":"TX"
```

How to make it match only within TX?

Comment: downvoters, please provide your comment - so that i can update the question accordingly.

Comment: Use json parsers to get your information. It's much easier. It'll be a nightmare to parse json using regex

Comment: i know that, but for performance improvement we do not want to use json parser.

Comment: forget json.. if it is a string, how do you match?

Comment: You are attempting to use regex to parse JSON, which is almost as bad as using regex to parse XML.  It is the wrong tool for the job.  Secondarily, non-greedy matching is part of the standard documentation, so the downvotes are because of lack of research on your part.

Comment: @JimGarrison, updated my question. it is not JSON anymore

Comment: @Abhijith, does not help

Comment: @KitKarson see this [`,("city.+"TX")`](https://regex101.com/r/ewHqqy/3)

Comment: @k-five what if that particular object is at the start of the json array? I know OP didn't present that case, but OP will get into that problem pretty soon

Comment: Any String manipulation on a JSON is going to end up being a hack. Probably not going to be a simple one-liner. Something like splitting the string on `},{`, then parsing the elements of the resulting array with a regex, would work. But it's an ugly hack. Or possibly `city(^city)TX` (I know, it's not the right format, it's for example's sake).

Comment: @KitKarson See this [`"city"[:"\w]+,[:"\w]+,[\w"]+:"TX"`](https://regex101.com/r/ewHqqy/4)

Comment: Also, any potential performance gain in running the regex will probably be overshadowed by the time it takes to get it up running and reliable, in lieu of a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not trying something like this , This looks much easier than regex.

```
public class TestStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s="\"city\":\"atlanta\",\"this1\":\"that1\",\"state\":\"GA\",\"city\":\"dallas\",\"this2\":\"that2\",\"state\":\"TX\"";

        String[] arr=s.split(",");

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            if(arr[i].contains("city")||arr[i].contains("state")){
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }

        }

    }

}
```